# Is there ways to write to logcat at different error levels with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

When I write to logcat in a normal Java Android app, I can write logs at specific levels, such as debug or error.

Is there a way I can do this in Flutter? All I have discovered so far is that the print() method will write to logcat, but not at any specific level.

Comment: You could try using the [logging](https://pub.dev/packages/logging) package.